# Uploading Videos using PHP

Tags: php

How to upload video files using PHP.
Actually,In my application some users r required to call a particular script and they have to pass videos as POST parameters.

Is it possible to manage and upload videos by passing them in post parameters, or first we should encode them before uploading .

In case of image uploading iPhone and Android Apps first encode the image in 64 bit encoding and then at runtime i decode them created image file at runtime and then save the file in a folder and it's path in databse. Can we do some similar stuff in case of videos also.

Answer (score 2):

Binary files are binary files.  It doesn't matter if they are images, videos, executables or whatever. The methods to transfer them over HTTP are the same.

Comment: Ok David How can i know the extension of Videos at runtime, because extension describes whether the videos will b able to play or not.Are there some functions in PHP , like we can have mimetypes in case of images(png,jpeg etc)

Comment: The extension doesn't determine if it can play or not. The combination of the container format, video codec and audio codec determine that. That is a complicated problem to solve (and a very different problem to the one expressed in your question).

Answer (score 1):

you should have no trouble uploading videos, you can check the file extension and put the file in a separate folder.

one thing you need to take into consideration if that you will need a lot of ram to upload large files so you could switch to a different server using javascript.

Comment: How can i know the extension of Videos at runtime, because extension describes whether the videos will b able to play or not.Are there some functions in PHP , like we can have mimetypes in case of images(png,jpeg etc)

Comment: you cannot check what type of file will be uploaded, you need to upload it first, then check the mime type and process accordingly. to check if it will play or not you might need to process it somehow using ffmpeg, you could have that run in a cron (something similar to youtube)